# instagram API :find user id from comment id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

i find comment id from my image

```
$comment= $instagram->getMediaComments($id_photo);
```

in $comment i have  :

```
 array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[317]
          public 'created_time' => string '1428490039' (length=10)
          public 'text' => string 'Keye?ðŸ˜‹kojast?' (length=16)
          public 'from' => 
            object(stdClass)[318]
              ...
          public 'id' => string '958566383632997763' (length=18)
```

i have comment id but i want find user id!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element from of the array should contain the user id that you are searching for, so you should be able to get it like this:

```
$comment[0]->from->id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $comment= $instagram->getMediaComments($id_photo)->data;
```

this is return id from user.